# Arithmetic on multiple columns/rows of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataset with a header (of years) and four columns that designate different characteristica

For each year, I want to divide all observations by 10^6, except for the first four columns. I know one can do

```
Data[,-1]/(10^6)
```

if one wants the first column to be left out, but what about if one needs four.

Best,

ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the sequence of 1:4, wrap it inside `(..)` and use the `-`.

```
Data[, -(1:4)] <- Data[,-(1:4)]/(10^6)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. If I want to do this permanently to the dataframe, but without losing the first four columns. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks so much! +1